# Need an event before an Open or Save Dialog is shown in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm looking for some mechanism that I can intercept all `TSaveDialog.Execute` or `TOpenDialog.Execute` methods with some sort of `OnDialogBeforeExecute` event.

I was wondering about `TVirtualMethodInterceptor`, using some sort of interposer class or somehow prefilling the `OnShow` event of each dialog.

Is anyone aware of a way of achieving this?

Comment: Is the OnShow event too late?

Comment: @DaveNottage It would be fine, but I don't want to change every dialog in the application.  The background is that I'm playing with ThinFinity.  Some dialogs I want to work on the client side in the browser and others on the server.

Comment: Could you explain why you need such mechanism? At first glance, you can replace TSaveDialog and TOpenDialog by your own version. Just copy their source in a new unit and modify it.

Comment: Using a unit with some Interceptor/Interposer classes come to mind.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your code then I would suggest inheriting from the TSaveDialog class and overriding the Execute method.

I have never used TVirtualMethodInterceptor, but this seems like a way to do the same thing at run-time - which would be helpful for code that is not yours or for which you have no source code access or for some reason cannot compile.  As you are using Thinfinity this may be the case with applications that are devekloped for use on a Windows desktop that you want to be independently maintained but have altered functionality when hosted.  That seems like a sensible approach.

Whichever way you go you can then include events for BeforeExecute and AfterExecute if you wanted to, and provide an alternative Execute with an OnExecute event that could fire instead of calling the inherited Execute.